# How to transfer full string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've a problem with transfering string data from view, it takes only first value from string. For ex, I've list of rooms which contain

```
Some action
Action in 
New room
```

When I click on first room (Some action) it takes only value "Some" and then me show alert that I've join "Some" room.

JS:

```
$('#rooms ul li').not('.nav-header').click(function () {

    $('#rooms ul li').not('.nav-header').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    var roomKey = $(this).data('value');
    hub.server.joinGroup(roomKey);
});
```

view:

```
<div id="rooms" class="well well-small">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">Rooms</li>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li data-value=@item.Name><a>@item.Name</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

While debugging, after click action it join to method that implement join room.

```
public void JoinGroup(string groupName) {..}
```

And in groupName it show only "Some".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add quotations around your `data-value` attribute:

```
<li data-value="@item.Name"><a>@item.Name</a></li>
```

---

Long Answer: What's happening here is that without the quotations this is being rendered loosely as the following:

```
<li data-value=Some action><a>@item.Name</a></li>
```

Javascript is interpreting this as 2 attributes:

- `data-value` = `Some`
- `action` = *nothing*

By adding quotations javascript will have a stricter structure to go by.